# Ordering of non-grouped columns in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to order the column display in order to force the columns with smallest values forward (higher z-index)?

Here's a [non-grouped column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/q8Udk/374/), which is accomplished by setting the `grouping: false` in the *column* settings for the *plotOptions*.

The idea is to always have the smaller bar on top  (if there are multiple bars, continue stacking the taller ones behind).  Notice this example uses transparency to circumvent that issue; however, the new color is not reflected in the legend.

I've scoured the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) but couldn't find much information.

Comment: I think that it is hard to find simple solution for your question. You can wrote custom function that can help you with your problem. Please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/w123o1je/10/

Comment: All series' points are in same graphic group and each series has its own group, so it is not possible to set different z-index for a point in series to make it on top of another series while rest of the points in first series is below. You could create more series - each can have z-index set.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you're asking, you would have to set a z-index value for each data point in each series (similar to how you can set a unique color for each data point, such as `data: { y: 10, color: 'blue' }`).

Unfortunately, the Highcharts API doesn't recognize z-index values for individual data points. Different z-index values can only be applied at the series level.

You may want to consider translucent columns with different widths, as shown in the "fixed placement columns" demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement

I hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: It's helpful. The wide columns just doesn't look attractive and the translucency is bad UX for accessibility. The problem with the series is there are some points that will still overshadow others. If there are 5 ungrouped columns, that's a lot of setting.